# Postgres получение предполагемого id

Tags: postgresql

как узнать id следующей записи? тип поля serial, соответственно автоинкремент

Comment: а зачем вам этот id? лучше используйте RETURNING

Comment: Вопрос нафига? Вот вы положим узнали следующее значение. А пока узнавали кто-то рядом взял и вставил туда запись. И что вы теперь с этим знанием делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращаю внимание, это не предполагаемое `id`, это число, которое можно
использовать в качестве `id` (не `id`!). Фактически вставленное `id` можно получить, вызвав

```
SELECT currval('myshema.tbl_item_id_seq')
```

в той же сессии после операции `insert`.

Последовательности гарантируют получение разных чисел - в одной транзакции,
или в параллельных, неважно. Числа могут повторяться только когда 
последовательность начнёт следующий цикл или произойдёт её сброс.

Если вы вызвали

```
SELECT nextval('myshema.tbl_item_id_seq')
```

то при вставке

```
INSERT INTO myshema.tbl_item(data,...,more_fields) 
VALUES('any_data',...,'any data n');
```

если поле задавалось как
`SERIAL\BIGSERIAL id`, полученный первой функцией не совпадёт с `id`
фактически вставленной записи.

И надо обязательно указывать

```
INSERT INTO myshema.tbl_item(id,data,...,more_fields) 
VALUES('результат предыдущего вызова nextval', 'any_data',...,'any data n');
```

Comment: можно захитрить и сделать так SELECT COALESCE(setval('techbase.item_id_seq', max(id)),nextval('techbase.item_id_seq'))  FROM techbase.item,
                    (SELECT 
                    nextval('techbase.item_id_seq')) as sel

Comment: Я б никогда так не стал делать. Грязный стиль, чреватый неприятностями, как минимум с производительностью.

Answer (score 1):

так получим текущий id

```
SELECT setval('vgok_site.pif_id_seq',nextval('vgok_site.pif_id_seq')-1);
```